# Why do does my program exit when I have my 2d array declared in main?

Tags: c++, arrays

I am attempting to read from a text file and store all the words in a 2d array but for some reason my code only works when my 2d array is declared as a global variable (which is not allowed for this project). When I put my 2d array in main (as shown in the code example) I get an exit code "Process finished with exit code -1073741571 (0xC00000FD)". Any idea as to why this happening?

```
char theWord[maxLength]; // declare input space to be clearly larger than largest word

char dict_array[maxWords][maxLength];

while (inStream >> theWord) {
    
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(theWord); i++) {

        dict_array[count][i] = tolower(theWord[i]);

    }

    if (strlen(theWord) >= 3) {
        count++;
    }
```

Comment: How big are `maxWords` and `maxLength`? Gut feeling, you have a stack overflow [TM]

Comment: maxWords is 93297 and macLength is 81.

Comment: `93297 * 81` is `7557057`, so it would take about 7 and a half megabytes to store that array, but your stack size is probably limited to 1 megabyte. You're gonna have to put that array elsewhere.

Comment: I'm trying to wrap my head around pointers at the moment. Is there a way I could utilize a pointer for this?

Comment: The problem isn't about the pointer, it's about what the pointer points to. You need to allocate that memory on the heap. Easiest, best, most recommendest way of doing that is to use `std::vector`.

Answer (score 4):

You've come to the right place to ask this, because `0xC00000FD` means Stack Overflow!

Your code fails because `char dict_array[maxWords][maxLength]` is larger than the available stack space in your process.  You can fix this easily by allocating the array using `std::vector`, `operator new[]`, or `malloc()`, or you can fix it the hard way by increasing the size of your stack (how to do that depends on your OS, and like I said it's the hard way, don't bother).

The most idiomatic solution to this problem is `std::vector<std::string>`.  Then you can allocate as much memory as your system has, and do so in a safe way with automatic deallocation (so-called RAII).

When it's a global variable it works fine because global variables are not allocated on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

That error indicates a stack overflow. Your arrays are too large to live inside the function. Either make them global or, preferably, allocate them dynamically with `new[]`